# Rewrite /category/cars into /topics/cars

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I know there are plenty of question and posts about this out there, however I couldn't find a solution or existing thread to my specific question.

If I list my categories and click on "cars" the url looks like this

`url/category/cars`

Is it simply possible to use some function in functions.php to change the word `category` into e.g. `topics`

`url/topics/cars`

Any ideas on that?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to Settings->Permalinks and change `Category Base` to topics, you won't even have to write any code to make the change, as wordpress includes this functionality by default.